# How to bind CTRL-X event in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to close the form/window when ctrl+x key was pressed in TK form.

I have this code below but I can't find the event for CTRL+X.

```
def quit(event):
    print "you pressed something"
    root.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Control_L>', quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try `'<Control-x>'`?

Comment: I see, it should be lowercase x. I tried upper-case letter.  I works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from acw1668. What I am trying earlier is the upper-case X, and it should be a lower-case like this `<Control-x>`.